# Command-line variables - in makefile - expand to weird values

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific):

> Target-specific variables have the same priority as any other
>   makefile variable.  Variables provided on the command line (and in the
>   environment if the '-e' option is in force) will take precedence.
>   Specifying the 'override' directive will allow the target-specific
>   variable value to be preferred.

So, a simple makefile, like:

```make
# A pattern-specific variable assignment.
% : foo += file

all : x ;

# Target is a double-colon w/o dependencies, so Make will ALWAYS run its commands.
x ::
    @echo '$(foo)'
```

Running, we get:

```console
# Override makefile-level variables, with a command-line assignment.
$ make foo=cmd
cmd cmd cmd

# Set the value in the environment, And tell Make to prefer it over any makefile-level definitions.
$ foo=env make --environment-overrides
env file file
```

Returning now, to the quote above, from the documentation:

> Variables provided on the command line (and in the environment if the '-e' option is in force) will take precedence.

It seems, that using either:

1. Command-line assignment.
2. Environment-set variables, AND using `-e` (`--environment-overrides`).

Have **both** the **same** effect, i.e. overrides the file-level (makefile) variable.

But, the results differ greatly. Remember that the value given in the command-line was: `cmd`, and the value given in the environment was: `env`.

Now, compare the values, given for a *command-line* override vs. an *environment* override:

1. `cmd cmd cmd` (for *command-line* override).
2. `env file file` (for *environment* override).

So, whereas for command-line, Make repeats the **same** value, i.e. `cmd`, **3 times**, for environment-override, the situation is **different**. That is, Make will "repeat" the environment-level value: `env` only **1** time, and then repeats - none other - than the **overridden** file-level value: `file`.

Now, not only is the situation completely different for an "override" from *command-line* vs. an "override" from the *environment*, which is strange by itself, the problem here is much bigger.

Since, Make rules to give "priority" for a command-line (or environment) value, why does it insist to append "other" values (as in the case of environment-override, where Make appends "file file"), or in the case of a command-line override (where Make **repeats the same value ***3*** times). Seriously?

How does it make sense at all? And what is the justification for these inconsistent and **strange** results?

Comment: The `env file file` result makes sense to me; the `cmd cmd cmd` result makes no sense.  I am having to guess at why there are two additions (rather than just one) to the basic `foo` macro, too.  I'll observe that if you happen to have a file `x` in your directory, the echo command won't be executed.

Comment: The reason there's two additions is that there's one from the `all` target and one from the `x` target, as both match `%`.

Comment: You are that person who posted all those oddly formatted bullet lists of complaints about make a while back aren't you? If you have bugs you wish to report to the make developers then do that. This isn't an appropriate forum for that. If you *are* actually interested in diagnosis of potentially-correct-but-odd behavior then I would suggest relaxing your tone a bit.

Comment: I fail to see how `cmd cmd cmd` is "potentially correct".

Comment: `cmd cmd cmd` is the easy case. `env file file` is the odd one. Answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer here is related to the answer to [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32091507/258523). (And possibly a bug in the env override version.)

The global variables and the target-specific variables are distinct variables.

The `cmd cmd cmd` result is because when you write `%: foo += file` make stores that as an addition to the current value of variable `foo` of the target-specific value of the variable `foo` which is `file`.

However, when you set `foo` on the command line make *overrides* the value of the target-specific variable `foo` to be `cmd` instead of `file`. So when make concats the variable each time it gets `cmd cmd cmd`.

That explanation should, I think, get you `env env env` then and I'm not sure why it doesn't. This could be a bug or it could be some other detail about how env override variables and target-specific variable values work. I'm not sure.

(Check the output of `make -p` for both these cases to see what I mean about the target-specific variable's value.)