# Are "global" makefile variables distinct from target-specific variables?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific):***

> All variables that appear within the
>   VARIABLE-ASSIGNMENT are evaluated within the context of the target:
>   thus, any previously-defined target-specific variable values will be in
>   effect.  Note that this variable is actually distinct from any "global"
>   value: the two variables do not have to have the same flavor (recursive
>   vs. simple).

***So, given a makefile:***

```make
% : foo += 1

all : x;

x ::
    @echo '$(foo)'

foo := 2
```

***And running, I get:***

```console
2 1 1
```

Taking a closer look at the quote above:

> All variables that appear within the
>   VARIABLE-ASSIGNMENT are evaluated within the context of the target.

It is impossible to explain how a ***target-specific*** definition like: `% : foo += 1`, will end up to **include** in its value, the "global" (i.e. not target or pattern-specific) value: `2`.

Much harder to justify it, when we look later, in the quote above:

> Note that this variable is actually ***distinct*** from any "global"
>   value: the two variables do not have to have the same flavor (recursive
>   vs. simple).

If, they are that "distinct", how come Make ends up expanding for the target `all`, a value that is a "salad" of values taken from the "global", and as well from the target-specific definition?

And what methodology did Make use to bring about the value `2 1 1`, because clearly, the value `1` **proceeds** the value `2` in the makefile above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are simply misunderstanding what the meaning of "distinct" meant there. It *did not* mean that they are two different variables. The meaning was clarified by the following fragment "the two variables do not have to have the same flavor". That's the point. The global variable `foo` and the target-specific variable `foo` are two different (but combined when expanded) variables.

With that in mind the output you get is exactly what you'd expect.

The **first** thing assigned to `foo` is the value `2` from the global assignment.

Only **after** that, during the target processing, is the `foo += 1` assignment processed (twice, once for `all` and once for `x`).

Which gets you `2 1 1` exactly as shown.